# How to check if string is similar to any string in list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to figure out if my string is similar to any list of items in list. My error is that it only iterates up to my list size, not for the length of my singular string. Any suggestions?

```
my_string = "aplpe"
my_list=["orange", "apple", "grape"]
correctamount=0
    if(my_string in my_list):
        print("Passed")
    else:
        if any(my_string in s for s in my_list):
            for i in range(len(my_string) + 1):
                if my_string[i] == my_list[i][i]:
                    correctamount += 1
                    print(correctamount)
                else:
                    correctamount == 0
                    print(correctamount)

            if((correctamount/len(my_list) + 1 ) > .75):
                print("Passed")
            else:
                print("Failure")
```

Comment: When you say similar, do you mean the same or equal?

Comment: Similar, read last if statement. If each index is identical, + 1 to correctamount. If not identical, dont add. If correct amount/length of string is more than 75% it passes. Meaning that word is similar, not identical

Comment: As a sketch for your fix: try to organize your code this way: 1- create a function that returns `True` or `False` if one string given as argument is similar to another one also given as argument. 2- Change your main code so that it _loops_ over every element of the array. If the result of calling the above function (with the current string looped over and the base string) is `True`, then print "pass" and stop. Otherwise, if the whole loop on your list ends without pass, print "failure".

Comment: By using the condition `any(my_string in s for s in my_list)` you're checking whether `my_string` is a _substring_ of any of the strings in `my_list` but this condition is never satisfied in fact `list(my_string in s for s in my_list)` is `[False, False, False]`

Comment: thats extremely helpful haha @user231437

Answer (score 3):

There's a library called `jellyfish` for this purpose - https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish

```
>>> import jellyfish
>>> jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(u'jellyfish', u'smellyfish')
2
>>> jellyfish.jaro_distance(u'jellyfish', u'smellyfish')
0.89629629629629637
>>> jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance(u'jellyfish', u'jellyfihs')
1
```

The library has different algorithms of string matching

```
Levenshtein Distance
Damerau-Levenshtein Distance
Jaro Distance
Jaro-Winkler Distance
Match Rating Approach Comparison
Hamming Distance
```

Answer (score 2):

To find similarity between strings there are many kinds of algorithms, Python has a library called [textdistance](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) which has all the algorithms.

The one I am going to use is Jaccard distance according to your requirements. You need to decide on the algorithm based on your needs.

```
import textdistance as td

similarity_perc = [td.jaccard.normalized_similarity(my_string, s) for s in my_list]
```

Similarity percentage for each string

```
[0.22, 1.0, 0.42]
```

Get the index of the most similar string

```
most_similar_index = similarity_perc.index(max(similarity_perc))
# Omitted not found check. Please do it yourself.
print(my_list[most_similar_index])
```

Output

```
apple
```

A benchmark of textdistance with other libraries is given [here](https://github.com/life4/textdistance#benchmarks) if you are looking to use this for a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in writing a clean code and separating out individual functionality, so that the code is easy to read and to contribute.

I defined a function `is_similar` to check the `similarity_percentage`.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
import math

def is_similar(my_string, test_string):
    min_len = min(len(my_string), len(test_string))
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, min_len):
        if(my_string[i] == test_string[i]):
            count = count+1
    similarity_percentage = count/len(my_string)
    print("Similarity Precentage: ", similarity_percentage)
    return ( similarity_percentage > 0.75 )

my_string = "aplpe"
my_list=["orange", "apple", "grape"]

if(my_string in my_list):
    print("Passed - Identical")
else:
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
        if(is_similar(my_string, my_list[i])):
            print("Passed - Similar with", my_list[i], sep=" ")
        else:
            print("Failure")
```

**Output:**

```
Similarity Precentage:  0.0
Failure
Similarity Precentage:  0.6
Failure
Similarity Precentage:  0.4
Failure
```

**Case 2:**

If

```
my_string = "aplpe"
my_list=["orange", "apppe", "grape"]
```

Then, output:

```
Similarity Precentage:  0.0
Failure
Similarity Precentage:  0.8
Passed - Similar with apppe
Similarity Precentage:  0.4
Failure
```

**Case 3:**

If

```
my_string = "aplpe"
my_list=["orange", "aplpe", "grape"]
```

Then, output:

```
Passed - Identical
```